# Angular Material datepicker is not honouring [min] and [max] restrictions

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

I have material date picker control (`dob`) defined like below. Problem I am having is that the `[min]` and `[max]` (set in HTML) values are not working - the `dob` control is valid just after entering first digit of the date. Any idea why?
HTNL:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>DOB</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="dob" #ref matInput [min]="10" [max]="10" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" required>
  <mat-hint>{{DATE_FORMAT}}</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="f['dob'].errors">Invalid DOB</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Module:

```
const CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput:  'yyyy-MM-DD',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'yyyy-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
...

providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS},

  ],
```

and finally in the component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.account.dob = moment(this.account.dob).format(Constants.dateFormat);
    var test = moment(this.account.dob, Constants.dateFormat).toDate();
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [this.account.title, Validators.required],
      firstName: [this.account.firstName, Validators.required],
      lastName: [this.account.lastName, Validators.required],
      email: [this.account.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      dob: [moment(this.account.dob, Constants.dateFormat).toDate(), [Validators.required]],
      password: ['',  [Validators.minLength(6)]],
      confirmPassword: ['',  [Validators.minLength(6)]],
      phoneNumber: [this.account.phoneNumber ], // Phone number is optional

    }, {
      validator: [MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword')]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`[min]` and `[max]` should be actual date.
If `[min]` is 10 days before from now and `[max]` is 10 days later from now, you can do it as this.

**ts**

```
minDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 10*86400*1000);
maxDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10*86400*1000);
      
ngOnInit() {
  // your code
}
```

**html**

```
<input formControlName="dob" #ref matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" required>
```